# Оплата товаров на сайте банковской картой

Tags: веб-программирование, интернет-магазин

Появилась задача сделать оплату на сайте по картам. У компании есть расчетный счет (банк Точка), надо что бы средства приходили на него.

Создать форму оплаты для ввода данных карты, а вот куда ее отправлять и как это делается?

Почитал что есть разные посредники типо робокассы, но интересует процесс без посредников. Подскажите с чего начать.

P.S. У точки есть интернет-эквайринг от яндекс кассы, а какие есть еще сервисы для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Собирать, передавать, снимать и вообще что-то делать с личными картами пользователей дело рискованное и сложное. Вы уверены, что с такими вопросами вы готовы сделать оплату с достаточной надежностью и сделать ее вообще? Онлайн оплата это не вставить данные в 4 поля и отправить по публичному API в банк. По факту платежные системы это как отдельный банк. Самое начало, продукт для работы с картами должен быть сертифицирован по стандарту PCI DSS и иметь защиту на уровне банковских систем. Вообще есть Яндекс.Касса, Робокасса, PayOnline, Интеллект Мани, PayPal, WalletOne, Сбербанк и другие.

Comment: @NTP Теперь не то что уверен, а заниматься этим однозначно не буду, а Вы бы могли подробнее описать процесс от формы карты до результата?

Comment: Выбираете поставщика этой слуги из перечисленных выше (или еще какого нибудь) и смотрите в их документации что от вас требуется. так как данные карты не могут вводится непосредственно на странице сайта не прошедшего сертификацию PCI DSS, то форму для ввода этих данных делает непосредственно та кампания, через которую вы работаете. Так что самому делать никакие формы для ввода не надо. Надо посмотреть API и выполнить на сайте то, что там требуется (переход на страницу системы, загрузка и вызов JS-кода делающего всплывающую форму и т.п.)